# C programming - Cannot open /dev/ttyS0 in blocking mode

Tags: gpio, serial, c

I am trying to open `/dev/ttyS0` in order to write over serial GPIO pin 8. I am using the Raspberry Pi Zero W and noted something strange. When I try to open `dev/ttyS0` in nonblocking mode, I am able to open it and my code does not hang at the `open()` system call. However, when I want to open it in `O_NONBLOCK` mode the `open()` system call hangs.

In the picture below one can see that `gdb` managed to hit line 18 which is after opening `/dev/ttyS0` in non-blocking mode.

[image]

The difference with the screenshot below is that this time the `O_NONBLOCK` is removed. This is what we want to have. However, for some mysterious reason I have not been able to figure out up to this point is why the `open()` system call is hanging trying to open `/dev/ttyS0` and create a file descriptor. I am running the program as `sudo` on the `pi` user so I am sure that permission is not the reason.

[image]

When I stop debugging in `gdb` it sits at line 44 of `open.c`. I could not find `open.c` using `find . -name "open.c"` command from the root directory but looking at [gnu libc line 44](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/io/open.c#L44) it potentially might be the variable argument length array option list?

[image]

Comment: Not a Pi specifc question.  I use O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK for the serial link.

Comment: Thanks for your message @joan, I don't want to use the O_NONBLOCK flag as we are specifically wanting to wait the `write()` system call to return once the bytes have been sent but for some mysterious reason when trying to open the `/dev/ttyS0` serial port on the Raspberry Pi the `open()` system call does not seem to return. How is this not a Pi specific question when this serial file exist on the Pi?

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text post TEXT (full working code) so others can run it.